# Best way to choose different child class to create new instance based on a boolean

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Hi my question is simple.
I have 3 classes, `BaseObject`, and `GoodObject` + `BadObject` that extends it:

```java
public class BaseObject {
  // some properties
}

public class GoodObject extends BaseObject {
  // good properties
}

public class BadObject extends BaseObject {
  // bad properties
}
```

And in the code, I'll need to choose to create `GoodObject` or `BadObject`, depending on boolean value `isGood`:

```java
public BaseObject businessLogic(){
  // ...
  return isGood ? new GoodObject(...) : new BadObject(...);
}
```

I don't like the idea for `businessLogic` to worry about which `BaseObject` instance to create, so plan to extract the `return isGood ? new GoodObject(...) : new BadObject(...);` into a factory class, so `businessLogic` will call something like `Factory.createObject(isGood, ...)`.
But not sure if there's a better or more elegant way.

---

An additional question, if I'm to use Factory class, what is the good way for me to pass in different properties? What I can think of is something similar to Builder pattern.

```
public class ObjectFactory {
  // all properties...

  public BaseObject withGoodProperties(good properties)   {
    // set good properties
    return this;
  }

  public BaseObject withBadProperties(bad properties)   {
    // set bad properties
    return this;
  }

  public BaseObject create(boolean isGood, base properties){
    return isGood ? new GoodObject(...) : new BadObject(...);
  }
}
```

Then in order to create a `GoodObject` i.e.: I need to call   `ObjectFactory.withGoodProperties(...).create(true, ...)`.
The problem is that it doesn't seem much simpler than the original
`return isGood ? new GoodObject(...) : new BadObject(...);`...

Comment: A factory class would be a reasonable solution to this: `BaseObjectFactory.create(isGood) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend going with the Factory approach, such as:

```
public class BaseObjectFactory {
    public static BaseObject create(boolean isGood) {
         return isGood ? new GoodObject(...) : new BadObject(...);
    }
}
```

If you want a Design Pattern approach. In my actual code, I'd probably have an if statement somewhere, and not be too concerned with this.

Comment: thanks @erikpragt, do you mind taking a look at the builder pattern I've just added at the end of the question?

Comment: I'd only use a builder if the properties are optional. If it's for example required that always the `withBaseProperties` is called, I wouldn't do it, since you'd be able to create an object in an invalid state, which you'd only find out at runtime. I'd use a constructor instead, but mostly, keep things simple.

Comment: (ps: the SO community doesn't really like "chatty" comments, nor multiple questions in 1 question. I'd recommend splitting your questions up in multiple questions, and be sure that it's a "factual" question, not an opinionated one)

Comment: will do that. thanks @erikpragt

Comment: sorry just one last question @erikpragt, as I can't think of a way to avoid `create an object in an invalid state` (`isGood` is true but only `bad properties` set). I think that's an unsolvable issue?

Comment: If you use the constructors of both GoodObject and BadObject, instead of using the builder pattern, I think it would be hard if not impossible to create an object in an invalid state. That's what constructors are for.

Comment: Since you mention Design Patterns, it should be noted this answer is a [Static Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-factory/info), which is unrelated to the Factory patterns in the famous GoF book.